# Checking For Json response is true or false in unit testing with Nunit?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

This is my method..

```
  public ActionResult AddModelAliasData(ModalAliasModel modalAliasModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ModelState.LogModelStateError();
            throw new BusinessException("COMMON_ERROR");
        }
        var response = _vehicleDataBusinessService.AddModelAliasData(modalAliasModel);
        return Json(response);
    }
```

As i am new to unit testing ... I am confused for some things, for the given above method in controller we are getting the json response in return. I want to check whether the return Json we are getting  back has success true or false How should i do it???

The Response object result is

```
 public class GetVehicleDataAliases : DefaultResponse
{
    public List<SearchData> FindData { get; set; }
    public List<VehicleDto> MakeDtos { get; set; }
}
```

The defaultResponse are Success , ErrorCode, ErrorMessage

I had wrote the unit test for this

```
  [Test]
    public void ShouldReturnJsonInAddMakeAlias()
    {
        var data = new GetVehicleDataAliases
        {
            MakeDtos = new List<VehicleDto>(),
            Success = true,
            FindData = new List<SearchData>()
        };

        mockVehicleDataBusinessService.Setup(x => x.AddMakeAliasData(It.IsAny<MakeAliasModel>())).Returns(() => data);
        var vehicleDataController = new VehicleDataController(mockVehicleDataBusinessService.Object);
        var result = vehicleDataController.AddMakeAliasData(makeAliasModel) as JsonResult;

        Assert.AreEqual(data, result.Data);
    }
```

But I am Able to clarify that is it the Right way to check for True or False Json result

Comment: What's the `response` object logic result?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code to it. Don't add code to comments. Also, it is compulsory to [show what you have tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and explain how it failed to work.

Comment: @NightOwl888 .. As i am new to unit testing so i dont know how should i try towards it ..Can't You tell me how should I do it??

Comment: @Ceaser What you tried so far looks correct for the shown method under test. It is unclear as to what is the problem.

Comment: @Nkosi Is it the right way for checking that the json response is true or false.??? I need to clarify that

Comment: The confusion is what are you trying to verify is true or false?

Comment: if the returned object matches the expected object and that object had success true then you have implicitly verified the expectation.

Comment: @Nkosi Can you show me how to do that

Comment: @Nkosi Could you put your project to github,let me fork and show it?